# Looking for a way to joint containers together in HTML

Tags: html, formatting

I'm trying to recreate an album cover into a website and I can't figure out how to line things up like this.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ6wh.png)

I prefer only using HTML but I'm not opposed to CSS : )

I should also mention that I don't really know a ton about HTML, I more just make things for fun, so sorry if I don't understand any questions or certain terms

Comment: I guess taking a HTML and CSS course before asking such a question might be a good start honestly. See [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a table, and then add some styling via CSS:

```html
<style>
td {
  border:4px solid red;
  padding: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 1000;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Heaven</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Radiation</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Radio</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Television</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```